# How to check if the installed wxPython is 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

How to check if the installed wxPython in my machine is 32-bit or 64-bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way:

- Run Python in a your terminal. On Windows, Python will usually mention 32-bit or 64-bit in the interpreter.
- **import wx** to make sure wxPython is installed for this version of Python.
- Now that we know you have wxPython installed for this version of Python, you can use Python's **platform** module to find out which version of Python you're using

Here's the code:

```
import platform
print(platform.architecture()[0])
```

You cannot install 64-bit wxPython with 32-bit Python (or vice-versa). So this should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:-

Step 1:-

Open cmd

Step 2:-

Type `pip show wxpython-phoenix`

That's it. It it shows your version of wxpython, then obviously your system is installed with it. Else install it by using the following command

`pip install wxpython-phoenix`

Done.